# missing keyword error in oracle, when I tried the concept of with-clause in CTE

Tags: oracle, common-table-expression

**below is my code:**

```
WITH Recursive EmployeeCTE AS

(
 Select Employee_Id as e_id, first_Name as e_name, Manager_ID as mgr_id
 From Employees
 Where Employee_Id =&emp_id

 union all

Select Employees.Employee_Id as e_id, Employees.first_Name as e_name, Employees.Manager_ID as mgr_id
 From Employees
 JOIN EmployeeCTE
 ON Employees.Employee_Id = EmployeeCTE.Manager_ID
)

Select E1.first_name, NVL(E2.first_Name, 'No Boss') as Manager_Name
From EmployeeCTE E1
LEFT Join EmployeeCTE E2
ON E1.Manager_ID = E2.Employee_Id;
```

Comment: Remove Recursive

Comment: I did that earlier. Then I got the following error :-                                          ORA-32039: recursive WITH clause must have column alias list
32039. 00000 -  "recursive WITH clause must have column alias list"
*Cause:    A WITH clause query referred to itself (recursive) but did
           not have a column alias list specified for it.
*Action:   Add a column alias list for the WITH clause query name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think from an error which you are getting, try to give alias as follows:

```
WITH EMPLOYEECTE(E_ID, E_NAME, MGR_ID) AS (
    SELECT
        EMPLOYEE_ID   AS E_ID,
        FIRST_NAME    AS E_NAME,
        MANAGER_ID    AS MGR_ID
    FROM
        EMPLOYEES
    WHERE
        EMPLOYEE_ID = &EMP_ID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID   AS E_ID,
        EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME    AS E_NAME,
        EMPLOYEES.MANAGER_ID    AS MGR_ID
    FROM
        EMPLOYEES
        JOIN EMPLOYEECTE ON EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID = EMPLOYEECTE.MGR_ID
)

Select E1.FIRST_NAME,
         NVL(E2.E_NAME, 'No Boss') AS MANAGER_NAME
FROM
    EMPLOYEECTE E1
    LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEECTE E2 ON E1.MANAGER_ID = E2.E_ID;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks. It worked successfully. But use E_ID, E_NAME, MGR_ID in the query outside with-clause

Comment: If this answer solved your question then please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it, so that your question is marked as resolved.